# Conditional transform of JSON value based on key and type with jq

Tags: json, bash, jq

I have a json file where I'd like to transform the value of some named keys from numeric (`0`/`1`) to boolean (`0`=>`false`, `1`=>`true`) using `jq`.

The transform should be re-entrant. If I run it on a (partially) transformed file, already converted keys should stay the same.

Given this json file:

```
{
  "foo": {
    "bar": {
      "color": "green",
      "visible": 0
    },
    "baz": {
      "fruit": "banana",
      "tasty": true
    }
  },
  "fubar": {
    "string": "hi",
    "value": "world",
    "enabled": 1,
    "sub": {
      "valuable": true,
      "empty": false
    }
  },
  "running": 1
}
```

and the following list of keys:

- .foo.bar.visible
- .foo.baz.tasty
- .fubar.enabled
- .fubar.sub.empty
- .running

I'd like jq to transform the above into this:

```
{
  "foo": {
    "bar": {
      "color": "green",
      "visible": false
    },
    "baz": {
      "fruit": "banana",
      "tasty": true
    }
  },
  "fubar": {
    "string": "hi",
    "value": "world",
    "enabled": true,
    "sub": {
      "valuable": true,
      "empty": false
    }
  },
  "running": true
}
```

I've come up with this (using the first two keys only to keep it short):

```sh
cat in.json | jq '.foo.bar.visible = (if .foo.bar.visible | type == "boolean" then .foo.bar.visible elif .foo.bar.visible == 1 then true else false end) | .foo.baz.tasty = (if .foo.baz.tasty | type == "boolean" then .foo.baz.tasty elif .foo.baz.tasty == 1 then true else false end)' > out.json
```

but there has to be a better way?

Also tried to put it into a `def` but that didn't work:

```
def numerictobool(key):
  $key = (if $key | type == "boolean" then $key elif $key == 1 then true else false end)
numerictobool(.network.eth0.enabled)
```

Comment: Don't use `cat`, just pass `in.json` as the second argument to `jq`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def numerictobool:
  if type == "boolean" then . else . == 1 end;

.
| .foo.bar.visible |= numerictobool
| .foo.baz.tasty |= numerictobool
| .fubar.enabled |= numerictobool
| .fubar.sub.empty |= numerictobool
| .running |= numerictobool
```

...emits as output, given your input:

```
{
  "foo": {
    "bar": {
      "color": "green",
      "visible": false
    },
    "baz": {
      "fruit": "banana",
      "tasty": true
    }
  },
  "fubar": {
    "string": "hi",
    "value": "world",
    "enabled": true,
    "sub": {
      "valuable": true,
      "empty": false
    }
  },
  "running": true
}
```

Comment: that works, now I'm trying to figure out a refinement where if the input key does not exist, it will not be created...

Comment: I figured it out myself:
`def numerictobool:  if type == "boolean" then . elif type == "number" then . == 1 else . // empty end; `